# Pattern Matching not working for MVEL.eval

Tags: java, regex, matching, mvel

I am trying to evaluate a pattern or regular based expression in Java using the MVEL library. However, the "matches" function is not working fine and is giving compilation error.

I have tried to create a an expression like below in MVEL but regular expression is not working fine.

Works Fine -

```
System.out.println(MVEL.eval("'5.00' == '5.00'"));
Answer : true
```

Does not work fine -

```
System.out.println(MVEL.eval("'5.00' matches '^-?\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?$'"));
Error Message : 
Exception in thread "main" [Error: unexpected token or unknown identifier:matches]
[Near : {... '5.00' matches '^-?\d+(\.\d{2})?$' ....}]
                    ^
[Line: 1, Column: 8]
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parseAndExecuteInterpreted(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:138)
    at org.mvel2.MVELInterpretedRuntime.parse(MVELInterpretedRuntime.java:47)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.eval(MVEL.java:92)
    at com.oracle.oci.ops.integrate.config.parser.MVELParser.main(MVELParser.java:24)
```

Can some one please help me out in resolving the issue?